# How to search for questions in one topic with a specific badge

Tags: support, tags, badges, search

I want to see all the questions with the badge Good question (or questions with an answer that is marked Good answer) in a particular topic (lets say Linux). How do I do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't search for posts awarded certain badges, but there is an equivalent search option. The Good Question badge takes 25 upvotes to be awarded, so simply search for questions with at least 25 votes that are in the Linux tag:

- [`[linux] votes:25`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5D+votes%3A25) will return all questions and answers tagged with [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) which have 25 votes
- [`[linux] votes:25 is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5D+votes%3A25+is%3Aquestion&submit=search) would return *only* questions out of those results
- [`[linux] votes:25 isaccepted:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinux%5D+votes%3A25+isaccepted%3A1&submit=search) would return *only* answers which have 25 votes *and* are marked as the accepted answer

Note, however, that this wouldn't catch posts which had previously been awarded the badge and then dropped below the threshold.

Comment: Thanks. This should do.. I just want to browse through good questions/answers to learn some new things.